# Hangouts server for group chat (XMPP)

Tags: xmpp, google-hangouts

I'm using a jabber/xmpp client to connect to google hangouts. Everything work fine. But now i want to join a **existing** group chat. How to do that? My client have the opportunity to connect to group chats. All i need is a server and a group chat id/name.

I've tried:

- server: hangouts.google.com
- server: talk.com
- server: groups.talk.com
- server: groups.hangouts.google.com
- server: groups.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [google documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4213661?hl=en) it is stated that you can not join group chat through xmpp client

> Hangouts currently supports 1-on-1 chat with third-party clients. Hangouts does not support the XMPP standard, including XMPP federation. However, third-party chat clients can continue to connect to the Google Talk network and also communicate in 1-on-1 chats with Hangouts through the Google Talk network.

Even if you can connect with xmpp client to google account and talk in 1-1 conversation, I don't believe you can join existing group.
However you can talk with google-talk users.